# String Concatenation in Front End Code (.ascx or .aspx)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

Is there any reason to use one of these techniques over the other?

There are **several strings** that get **created in the code behind**:

```
protected string String1;
protected string String2;
protected string String3;
protected string String4;
```

They are **used in the front end code** and can be **printed to the screen using**:

```
<%#String1%><%#String2%><%#String3%><%#String4%>
```

**Alternatively** these can be **printed using**:

```
<%#String1 + String2 + String3 + String4%>
```

The **second technique** seems a little **easier to read**.  The thought popped into my head that it may be slightly less efficient depending on how the `<#%%>` is evaluated compared to the `+`.

**Is there a difference in efficiency that makes one way better than the other?**

Comment: "... it may be slightly less efficient depending on how the <#%%> is evaluated compared to the +" - can you please explain your reasoning of what lead you to that conclusion?

Comment: why not simply <%# String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}", String1, String2, String3, String4)> ?

Comment: I say "may" because I am unsure and haven't come to any conclusion.  The thought originates from techniques I use in code behind. I use StringBuilder to do string concatenation because it is more efficient than using the plus operator.  That made me think it may not be best to use here.

Comment: @Infer-On - If that technique is most efficient than that is what I want to use.  Is it better than the others?

Comment: Just a thought but have you tried using string.Concat ?

Comment: @RacerNerd Using the + operator here would be more efficient than using a `StringBuilder`, given that the number of strings to concat is known at compile time.  There isn't anything that you could do that would be *more* efficient than using the `+` operator when you have 4 string variables to concat together.

Comment: @matt_lethargic The + operator is going to be transformed by the compiler into a call to `string.Concat`.  You could use it explicitly if you feel it's more clear, but in terms of functionality it would actually result in literally the exact same IL being generated.

Comment: Related to this question being opinion based... I am asking what is the most efficient way to do this.  I expect one way to work faster than the other so I am confused as to how this is opinion.  I see 3 ways to answer, 1 faster than 2, 2 faster than 1, both the same.  These 3 answers are free of opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for the second case it'll be transforming that code into a single call to `string.Concat`, which is as efficient of a method as you can get for concatting 4 C# strings together.

I'm not positive how ASP goes about taking each component of the markup and building a single string out of the content, but I would be shocked to find out that it used a silly strong concatenation method that ends up building an intermediate string and copying over the entire page's HTML every time a new component is added in.  I think it's a pretty safe bet to assume that some reasonably sensible method is used, most likely either `StringBuilder`, writing the content to a stream, or some other comparable method of efficiently appending a series of strings together.

Comment: Is this saying that the second technique is probably as efficient as the first?

Comment: @RacerNerd They're both going to be comparable, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Asp.net engine will not concat the following string to each other it just render 4 times and place it in the html code

```
<%#String1%><%#String2%><%#String3%><%#String4%>
```

While below string will concat on server side and render 1 time only. definitely this is easy to read and understand.

```
<%#String1 + String2 + String3 + String4%>
```

Comment: All of this code is done on the server side.  Nothing here is ever done on the client side.

Comment: @Servy Concatenation will take place in 2nd second but not in first code

Comment: It's the difference between concatting the four strings together and then appending it onto the rest of the page's HTML content, or appending each string to the end of the page's HTML content each in turn.  Since this particular expression is one aspect of the page's content that's being concatted together with a bunch of other pieces, yes, the strings are being concatted together either way, it's just a question of how.  And once again, this is *all* still server side.  Nothing here is client side.

Comment: I feel like this answer is basically my question reworded.  I realize there is a difference in the way these are handled by the server and that is why I ask the question.  The question is, Which one works faster?